# Validating GridView Rows

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I just need some suggestions of how to approach validating a GridView column.

What I currently have is a GridView with three columns (Tests, Results, Date Completed).

For the Test column it will be pre populated based on a SQL Script. The Results Columns is empty textboxes that the user will have to enter the Test Result and the date column is the same as Results column containing empty textboxes for the user to enter the Date of the Test Being Completed. I want to be able to Validate the Results column, currently the date column I am using calendar extender, masked edit extender and validator and that is working just fine. Now for the results column the Validation will be different based on the Test, the test ABC can have a result only being between 2-7 while Test CBA can be True/False and so on. I just dont know how to approach of validating each field. I hope you can help me out. Thanks.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdResults" runat="server"
    CssClass="gridview" 
    RowStyle-CssClass="gridview_itm" 
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="gridview_aitm" 
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview_hdr" 
    Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Test")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>                                                
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Result">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbResult" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>                                                
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Completed">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Image ID="imgCalendar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Sugar2006/images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png" ImageAlign="Middle" />
                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="ce" runat="server" TargetControlID ="tbDate" PopupButtonID="imgCalendar" />        
                <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="mex" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="tbDate" 
                    Mask="99/99/9999" 
                    MaskType="Date"
                    MessageValidatorTip="true"
                    OnFocusCssClass="MaskedEditFocus"
                    OnInvalidCssClass="MaskedEditError" />
                <asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="mev" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="tbDate"
                    ControlExtender="mex" 
                    Display="Dynamic" 
                    InvalidValueMessage="This date is invalid" Font-Bold="True" 
                    ForeColor="#D50000" />
            </ItemTemplate>                                                
        </asp:TemplateField>                                                            
    </Columns>        
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you simplify your question by just concentrate on the validation since this is not a GridView question at all, is it? It's also not clear what you're actually expecting(what are `test abc` and `test cba`?).

Comment: Well I think it is because I want to do a GridView Field Validation...

Comment: What I mean by "Tests" are the medical Tests... The Test - Flue Shot -  I was just simply specifying a sample Test (ABC) (CBA) ...

Comment: Your question is bit unclear. But I guess you try to update the data since you already retrieve data to one column. if so you can add another **ItemTemplate** which hold the update button where you can do validations to reach row. For validation you an use **JavaScript/JQurey** in client side or you can also do it in code behind in **GridView.RowUpdating**

Comment: Add all your required validators and enable/disable them in RowDataBound according to the "Test-value"(i assume that this is some kind of type). And avoid such examples like `test abc` in future since they're confusing and pointless(in terms of understandability).

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I am trying to avoid having an Update field for user to click on. I was wondering if there is anything similar I could so like to the Date Completed Field but the only thing is that the Results column will have different validations.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Thanks for your comment... I don't fully understand how do add Required Validators and enable/disable them in RowDataBount... Would this be a separate field you mean?

Comment: I really wanted to see If I can use ajax similar to Date Completed Field but I dont know if that is going to work.

Comment: @Nick what you mean by "the Results column will have different validations"

Comment: @huMptyduMpty - Each Medical Test will have different Results - For example client wants Test (Dilated Eye Exam) to only accept True/False while the result LDL Cholesterol will be numeric ...

Comment: @Nick: Then you have to do the process as Tim Schmelter mentioned above. Basically add all the types of validation you expect as required field validators and in the **GridView.RowDataBound** check your **Tests** value for row and enable the necessary validator depends on the value

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Adding my comment as answer</sub>

Add all your required validators and enable/disable them in [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) according to the "Test-value"(keeping my example abstract as your question).

```
  void GrdResults_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        String testValue = rowView["Test"];
        CompareValidator cv1 = (CompareValidator)e.Row.FindControl("cv1); // checks between 2-7
        CompareValidator cv2 = (CompareValidator)e.Row.FindControl("cv2); // checks true/false
        cv1.Enabled = testValue.ToUpper().Equals("ABC");
        cv2.Enabled = !cv1.Enabled;
    }
  }
```